# Try to implement a simple text parser in javascript

Tags: javascript

i´m trying to bring a simple text parser from Java to Javascript.

The requierement is to transform a given csv file in to another format. The original file list a number of values according to one id in certain lines:

for example:
11111; 12; 23; 23 ;....
11111; 32; 12; 12 ;....

So the first value is an Id and the other values are according to this Id.
Now I need the same file with alle the values according to the one Id in a single line.
the result should be something like:
11111;12; 23; 23; 32; 12; 12 ;....

I already achieved this with a simple Java class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("t2_lines.csv", "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("t2.csv"));

        String previousId="";
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] words = line.split(";");
            String id = words[0];
            if (previousId.equals(id)){
                // the loop starts at 4 to cut out some unneded values
                for(int i=4;i<words.length;i++) {
                    writer.print(words[i]+";");
                }
            }else{
                writer.println("");
                for(String word : words)
                writer.print(word+";");
                previousId = id;
            }
    }
        br.close();
        writer.close();
    }
```

and now I try to rebuild this thing in Javascript by read in a file from the client and present the result in a textfield - but unfortunately i´ve never implemented anything in Javascript before...

This is my approach so far:

```
window.onload = function () {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var origFileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('origFileDisplayArea');
var reformatFileDisplayArea= document.getElementById('reformatFileDisplayArea');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsText(file);

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var result = reader.result;
            var table = parse(result);
            origFileDisplayArea.innerText = table;
        }
    } else {
        origFileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
    }
});
}

function parse(input) {
var previousId = "";
var table = "";
if (typeof input !== "undefined")
var lines = input.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i <= lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    if (typeof line !== "undefined")
    var words = line.split(";");
    console.log("words length: ", words.length);
    for (var j = 0; j <= words.length; j++ ) {
        var word = words[j];

        if (typeof word !== "undefined") {
            word.toString();
            var id = words[0];
            if (previousId === id) {
                for (var jj = 4; jj <=words.length; jj++){
                    console.log("jj: " + jj)
                    table += words[jj]+";";
                }
            }else {
                table += "\n";
                for (var word in words) {
                    table += word + ";";
                    previousId = id;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

return table;
}
```

But unfortunately i´m stucked now with undefined values and the whole thing took ages to run.

So any hints/help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for the *FileReader*, I can't see a way to avoid that in this context. That doesn't look like where you have the problem.

As for `parse`, the `split` method can use up a lot of memory so I'd avoid using it on the whole file, and `for..in` is not designed for looping over an *Array*.

```
function parse(str_in) {
    var i = -1, j = -1,
        str_out = '',
        last_id = '',
        words;
    str_in += '\n'; // not sure if necessary - let the last line pass `while`
    // loop by seeking out the next new line
    // i = old_index + 1
    // j = next \n after old_index
    // .slice(i, j) gives just the line
    while (-1 !== (j = str_in.indexOf('\n', i = j + 1))) {
        words = str_in.slice(i, j).split(';')
        // loop words to trim whitespace here if you want
        if (last_id === words[0]) // throw away first item if on the same id
            words = words.slice(1);
        else {
            last_id = words[0];
            if (str_out.length) // lazy prevent first char newline
                str_out += '\n';
        }
        str_out += words.join(';'); // if you trimmed witespace, re-add here
        // if you don't have a final semicolon, add it too
    }
    return str_out;
}
```

Now

```
parse('11111; 12; 23; 23 ;\n11111; 32; 12; 12 ;');
// "11111; 12; 23; 23 ; 32; 12; 12 ;"
```

---

Alternatively, you might find it easier to write methods similar to what you're used to in *Java* so you can work with minimal changes, e.g.

```
function ReadLineGenerator(text) {
    var start = -1, end = -1;
    return function readLine() {
        if (end < start) {
            start = end = -1;
            return null;
        }
        start = end + 1;
        end = text.indexOf('\n', start);
        if (end !== -1)
            return text.slice(start, end);
        else
            return text.slice(start);
    };
}
// example usage
var str = 'a\nb\nc',
    f = ReadLineGenerator(str),
    line;
while (null !== (line = f()))
    console.log(line);
// "a", "b", "c" logged
// line === null
```